# How do I make UILabel's text flush with the top of its bounds?

Tags: uikit, uilabel

If I create a `UILabel`, set its `text` and call `sizeToFit`, there is still a small vertical gap between the top of the `text` and the top of the `UILabel`'s `bounds`. How do I either eliminate the vertical gap, or calculate it so that I can extend `-[UILabel drawTextInRect:]` and eliminate it myself?

I've made a small [test app](https://github.com/hborders/EliminateLabelTopVerticalSpace) to demonstrate the vertical space issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS creates a synthetic leading for all fonts, even those which don't have leading specified in the font files.

The only way to achieve this is to draw the label text yourself.